# figure style not applied to the image tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ckeditor

i'm trying to display html text stored in server data base.  but the style of figure tag not working and  the image is displaying in original size

```html
<body>
    <figure style="width:50%;">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/800/300" >
    </figure>
</body>
```

Comment: max-width:100% to img

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="width:100%"` to the `img` tag

```html
<body>
    <figure style="width:50%;">
        <img src="http://localhost:8080/images/201217_StimmenFIFAWahl_16x9.webp" style="width:100%;">
    </figure>
</body>
```

Comment: i  using ckeditor to save these text in a data base ... i can't change the style of image. the text is stored in a data base i have only permission to display it with htmlinner directive